# Launch/Create Android Emulator that does not have (without) root access

Tags: android, android-emulator

I need to run a security test on one of our Android mobile applications.

1. It must not run if the device is rooted.
2. It should run as expected on non-rooted devices.

I have tested part 1 without issue and found it to work as expected.

However, I cannot seem to create an emulator using the AVD Manager that will not start with root access.

-Is there a command line method to reduce the emulator instance to non-rooted at startup? 
-Failing that, is there a method to send an adb shell command (or other command line call) to reduce the permissions to the installed application?

Thanks!

Edit for @Fred. 
I have opened the shell and changed it to the user id (uid) of the application under test. Note that in the image you can see the command, "adb shell su u0_a53" and then the next prompt includes the user, "u0_a53@generic_x86_64" as the returned shell and has the "$" indicating non-root access. However, when opening the application under test on the emulator, the application detects the device is rooted. What am I missing?

[See attached image - click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQu7R.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way using SU to change super user to non root, see answer in this so question for directions:

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/60599/how-to-get-non-root-access-on-emulators

Comment: Yeah I saw that link. The answer mentioned speaks to running non-rooted commands. It doesn't really modify the emulator' itself to be in a non-rooted state. This does not solve my problem.

I don't need to run a non-rooted shell. I need the emulator to launch in a non-rooted state. 

Thanks.

Comment: Shane when you modify SU to run as non-rooted what do you think that means? No doing that way will not automate it but its the only way..in that once emulator launches you do that SU command sequence via the adb commandline and when you launch the app the emulator itself is in non-root state launching the app in non root state.

Comment: Please refer to the edit i just made on the initial question. I've attached a print screen of what I'm observing. I 'modified' the shell to be using the user ID of the app.. When i open the app, however, it still detects that the emulator is rooted and pops the message.

What am I missing here? 

I tried this before I posted this question., hence my previous response. If I'm doing this wrong, can you describe what I should be doing instead?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, my question was fundamentally flawed. The environment i'm trying to achieve could not be created with an emulator as part of the security test checks to see if the phone is in 'release' mode, in addition to looking for the presence of 'su'. After conferring with several other teams, I have decided to obtain a physical phone for testing this security restriction.